# What have I missed in Windows Terminal settings.json?

Tags: windows, git, terminal, windows-terminal

I just start to customize **Windows Terminal**.

I would like to add **Git** and it opens the git-bash.exe **outside** of the program.

What have I missed in the settings.json?

[image]

That's the settings.json "profiles" -> "list" array

```
{
"guid": "{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001}",
"name" : "Git",
"commandline" : "I:/Git/git-bash.exe",
"hidden": false,
"icon" : "I:/Git/mingw64/share/git/git-for-windows.ico",
"padding": "8, 8, 8, 8",
"closeOnExit" : "always",
"snapOnInput": true,
"historySize" : 9001,
"startingDirectory": "%USERPROFILE%"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`git-bash.exe` and `Windows Terminal` may be the same kind of applications -- terminal. They are different from shells, such as `cmd`, `powershell`, `bash`, `sh`, `zsh`.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/61969136/11831045