# Git Bash in Windows Terminal is opening in a separate window

Tags: git, git-bash, windows-terminal

I want to add git bash to the windows terminal, however, when I add a new git bash tab in the terminal the git bash opens in a different window.

Here's my configuration:

```
{
    "guid": "{--------------------}",
    "acrylicOpacity" : 0.75,
    "closeOnExit" : true,
    "colorScheme" : "Campbell",
    "commandline" : "C:\\Users\\anonymous\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Git\\git-bash.exe",
    "cursorColor" : "#FFFFFF",
    "cursorShape" : "bar",
    "fontFace" : "Consolas",
    "fontSize" : 10,
    "historySize" : 9001,
    "icon" : "C:\\Program Files\\Git\\mingw64\\share\\git\\git-for-windows.ico",
    "name" : "Git Bash",
    "padding" : "0, 0, 0, 0",
    "snapOnInput" : true,
    "useAcrylic" : true
}
```

Output:

[image]

What am I missing?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

I don't know if that's the correct solution, but I tried changing it to open the `sh.exe` in the bin folder, with the argument `--login` and it works now.

**EDIT**

As mentioned in the comments, `bash.exe` can also work. (Anything in the `bin` folder)

Comment: Yes, this is an appropriate solution, use any of the shells in the 'Git/bin' directory, you can also use `bash.exe` instead of `sh.exe`.

Comment: It's the "correct" solution if you want a bash instance that doesn't open in a new window. However that bash doesn't have a git command. I named it "NoGit Bash" in my config, and "Git Bash" still opens in a new window.

Comment: Haven't you noticed issues with messed up output of logs when running builds in bash.exe or sh.exe? When I run the build from git-bash.exe, I don't see any log output issues..

Comment: whats the difference between `\git-bash` and `\bin\bash`?

Comment: is `\bin\bash` git-related, or is it just regular MinGW bash?

Comment: Choosing `C:\Program Files\Git\bin\sh.exe` worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

Select **git-cmd** instead of **git-bash** while adding profile in terminal an change the starting directory in settings by selecting Git Bash profiles.

**My settings:**

```
    {
        "commandline": "C:\\Program Files\\Git\\git-cmd.exe",
        "guid": "{******************************}",
        "icon": "C:\\Program Files\\Git\\git-for-windows.ico",
        "name": "Git Bash",
        "startingDirectory": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs"
    },
```

[image]

Comment: it worked! But the home dir is win\sys32

Comment: i take it back. It does start as new tab, but that just it! Nothing works

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Answer (score 4):

If you installed git using scoop, you can use `C:\Users\xxxxx\scoop\apps\git\current\bin\bash.exe` as command line.

Additionally if you want the nice matching icon you can use `C:\Users\xxxxx\scoop\apps\git\current\mingw64\share\git\git-for-windows.ico` in the icon field.